# Inject compile-time properties with build.gradle (without modifying it)

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

We have this in an android project I'm working on:

```
android {
    ...
    productFlavors {
       dev {
           buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"https://somedevurl.com\""
       }
       prod {
           buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", "\"https://someprodurl.com\""
       }
    }
}
```

This is a simple approach and it works very well but I'd like to be able to inject keys/secret at compile time **(I don't want those committed into my `build.gradle` for security reasons)**. My approach so far is to inject a `strings.xml` file at compile time and use to access this secret from `AndroidManifest.xml`, my problems with this are that **we need to be careful of not committing this file / having this file referenced in `.gitignore`**, and **it feels like a hack**

As an alternative to that, I made the following:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            Properties flavorProps = new Properties()
            flavorProps.load(project.rootProject.file("./app/config/dev.properties").newDataInputStream())
            flavorProps.each { p ->
                def resValuePrefix = "RES_VALUE_"
                if (p.key.startsWith(resValuePrefix)) {
                    resValue "string", p.key.substring(resValuePrefix.length()), "\"${p.value}\""
                }
                def buildConfigPrefix = "BUILD_CONFIG_"
                if (p.key.startsWith(buildConfigPrefix)) {
                    buildConfigField "String", p.key.substring(buildConfigPrefix.length()), "\"${p.value}\""
                }
            }
        }
        prod {
            Properties flavorProps = new Properties()
            flavorProps.load(project.rootProject.file("./app/config/prod.properties").newDataInputStream())
            flavorProps.each { p ->
                def resValuePrefix = "RES_VALUE_"
                if (p.key.startsWith(resValuePrefix)) {
                    resValue "String", p.key.substring(resValuePrefix.length()), "\"${p.value}\""
                }
                def buildConfigPrefix = "BUILD_CONFIG_"
                if (p.key.startsWith(buildConfigPrefix)) {
                    buildConfigField "String", p.key.substring(buildConfigPrefix.length()), "\"${p.value}\""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I create a file per flavor under `app/config/`, I read every property and if the property starts with `BUILD_CONFIG_` I import this property as `buildConfigField`, and if it starts with `RES_VALUE_` I import that property as `resValue`.

This approach satisfies me (Now I can add compile time properties by modifying only the *.properties file) but the code is copypasted for each flavor.

My questions are:

**Do you know of a better way to do this?**

**If not, is there a way to extract this code in order to reduce code duplication?**